# Histogram, density kernel and normal distribution

Tags: r, return, histogram, curve-fitting, kernel-density

I want to plot a histogram, density (Gaussian kernel) and the fitted corresponding normal distribution, of the simple losses of the Allianz SE company.
(That means, the simple losses are minus the simple returns)

I have the following code:

```
hist(alvsloss,breaks = 100, freq=F,main="Histogramm,
 density curve (gaussian kernel) of Allianz simple losses ",xlab="loss in percent",ylab="density")
lines(density(alvsloss), col="red", lwd=2)
curve(dnorm(x, mean = mean(alvsloss), sd = mean(alvsloss)), add=TRUE, col="blue", lty="dotted")
```

Now I have the first problem:

```
The fitted normal distribution is not drawn, I get the (german) error message:

In dnorm(x, mean = mean(alvsloss), sd = mean(alvsloss)) :
  NaNs wurden erzeugt
```

The normal distribution curve is not plotted.

The second is a question in general:
If I leave out the normal distribution, so I only have the histogram and the density. Than I can change between frequency true and false via the command

```
 freq=T
```

or

```
 freq=F
```

I attached a screenshot of both pictures (I have to upload it, since I have not at least 10 reputations). I do not understand them, if I have freq=T that means, I have the density values at the y axis. So there should be values like 0.0012 or 0.1, but not values of 300 or 400, density should be relative values? Also the kernel does not match in any way, it is clearly wrong? If I have freq=F I get the right picture. Now I have absolute values, so e.g. there were 30 cases in which I had a return which was about 0.0 (the middle high peak), right? Now the density does fit, but I would have expected it to do not fit in this case, since I thought it is in freq=T values, so it should be another way round, in this picture it should be wrong?

If this is answered, I would have further questions:
I do not like the x axis, how can I have a more detailed scaling?
Is it right to say the following: The tail on the right from 0.5 up to 0.1 is heavier than the tail on the left side, so in this area we have a higher probability of losses than of gains? Whereas the extreme values occur only on the left side: Values of -0.2 and even one with approx -0.4. So extreme losses in this case are not occurring, whereas extreme gains are realized? Is this right?

What is my mistake, I cannot see it?

Screenshot:

You can find the data [here](http://uploadeasy.net/upload/nsorc.rar)

It is the alvsloss data

The complete solution is:

```
hist(alvsloss,breaks = 100, freq=F,main="Histogramm, density curve (gaussian kernel) of Allianz simple losses ",xlab="loss in percent",ylab="density")
lines(density(alvsloss), col="red", lwd=2) 
curve(dnorm(x, mean = mean(alvsloss), sd = sd(alvsloss)), add=TRUE, col="blue",lwd=2)
```

which gives the following picture:

[image]

seems to be correct, right?

Comment: Should the standard deviation for the normal curve really be equal to the mean of the data? What is the mean? Also, where do we get this data from? We can't supply a proper answer without being able to work with the same data you are working with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The R help says :

> logical; if TRUE, the histogram graphic is a representation of frequencies, the counts component of the result; if FALSE, probability densities, component density, are plotted

When the `freq` attribute is `TRUE`, the number of times the values appear in the data is plotted. If you have a vector with 400 times the value 1 and 300 times the value 0, the height of the bars would be 400 and 300 when `freq=TRUE`, and 4/7 and 3/7 when `freq=FALSE`.

For the second part of your question, if there are `NA` values in your vector, you have to calculate the mean with :

```
mean(...,na.rm=TRUE)
```

Furthermore, as ndoogan said, I think there is a typo in your code. Try this instead :

```
dnorm(x, mean = mean(alvsloss,na.rm=TRUE), sd = sd(alvsloss,na.rm=TRUE))
```

Finally, you cannot use `curve` to plot a vector. It works only for functions. So you can try :

```
lines(dnorm(x, mean = mean(alvsloss,na.rm=TRUE), sd = sd(alvsloss,na.rm=TRUE)), col="blue", lty="dotted")
```

or

```
curve(dnorm,from=ToBeFilled,to=ToBeFilled,col="blue", lty="dotted",mean = mean(alvsloss,na.rm=TRUE), sd = sd(alvsloss,na.rm=TRUE)))
```

`ToBeFilled` are respectively the bounds of the interval where you want to plot.

Comment: ok, one more question:
Now I have at the y-axis values of 25 or 30, I am using freq=F

How can I interpret this value? This is the bar, which is the maximum, approx loss is around to 0.0

So the probability of this bar would be what? I have to know the width of this bar right? So $30*width$ is the probability of occurance of losses around 0.0? How can I get the exactly range of this bar? E.g. from -0.005 up to 0.005?

Comment: but it is working with curve?

curve(dnorm(x, mean = mean(alvsloss), sd = sd(alvsloss)), add=TRUE, col="blue",lwd=2)

seems to work or not?

Comment: lines(dnorm(x, mean = mean(alvsloss,na.rm=TRUE), sd = sd(alvsloss,na.rm=TRUE)), col="blue", lty="dotted")

does not work:

object x not found

Comment: You must put quantiles instead of x. For example, `seq(0,1,length.out=100)`. `curve` can work but not in the way you wrote it in your question : it has to be applied to a function. If you get the results of you `hist`command by typing `a <- hist(...)`, you can get all the informations you need about the histogramm : `a$breaks` and `a$density` for example which enable you to compute probabilities.

Comment: I edited my answer. The way I put this code into R works, since I get nor error message and I get a nice picture?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where to get the data you are working with, but try setting your standard deviation in the dnorm plot to the standard deviation of your data...

```
curve(dnorm(x, mean = mean(alvsloss), sd = sd(alvsloss)), add=TRUE, col="blue", lty="dotted")
```

Comment: thanks! I can only accept one answer as THE answer, but this helped me!

Comment: @StatTistician If you want to say thanks, you may be able to "up vote" the answer. Also, you're welcome.